# function attached SweetAlert Confirmation button not works

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am not fluent in javascript and I cannot understand very well because the .then (result) does not work for me. That is, it is never confirmed,
so, it never enters the if conditional. The code is the same as that offered [in the SweetAlert api](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). Where does that variable result come from?

All the code of my script. Try to use Sweet alert for confirmation a delete form... No works the button confirmation in this way:

```php
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Borradores')

@section('content_header')
    <h1 class="text-center">Listado de borradores</h1>
@stop

@section('content')



{{-- {{ route('admin.create') }} --}}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href=""><i class="fas fa-table mr-2"></i> Crear nuevo Articulo</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <table id="tablaArticulos" class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablas">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Entradilla</th>
                    <th>¿Publicar?</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {{-- {{ route('admin.destroy', $post ) }} --}}

                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td>{{ $post->category->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->extract}}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('admin.edit', $post) }}"><i class="fas fa-cross"></i></a></td>
                        <td>
                            {{-- {{ route('admin.edit', $post ) }} --}}
                            <form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $post->id) }}" method="post" class="delete-form">
                                @csrf
                                @method('delete')
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{route('admin.edit', $post)}}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </form>        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Entradilla</th>
                    <th>¿Publicar?</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.card -->
@stop

@section('css') 
    <style>
        .fotoTabla{
            width: 60px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css">
@stop

@section('adminlte_js')
    @stack('js')
    @yield('js')

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    
    {{-- Datatables responsive --}}
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.7/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    {{-- id Databales --}}
    <script>
    $(function () {

        $(".tablas").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth:false
        });
    });

    </script>

    @if (session('crear'))

        <script>
            Swal.fire({
                title: '{{ session("crear") }}',
                icon: 'success',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2500,
                timerProgressBar: true
            })  
        </script>
    @endif

    @if (session('message'))

        <script>
            Swal.fire({
                title: '{{ session("message") }}',
                icon: 'success',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2500,
                timerProgressBar: true
            })  
        </script>
    @endif

    @if (session('alert'))

        <script>
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'ATENCIÓN',
                text: '{{ session("alert") }}',
                icon: 'warning',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 3500,
                timerProgressBar: true
            })  
        </script>
    @endif

    <script>
    // Mensaje de alerta al pulsar el Botón de borrar en las tablas
        $('.delete-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let nombreElemento =  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerText;
            console.log(nombreElemento);
            Swal.fire({
                title: `¿Estás seguro de borrar ${nombreElemento}?`,
                text: "Recuerda que esta acción es irreversible",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#50f8ac',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                focusCancel: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok, borralo', 
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar' 
                }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    this.submit();
                }
                });
        });

</script>

@stop
```

[image]

I have placed two console.log () before the .then and a else in the conditional

```
   <script>
    // Mensaje de alerta al pulsar el Botón de borrar en las tablas
$('.delete-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let nombreElemento =  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerText;
    Swal.fire({
        title: `¿Estás seguro de borrar ${nombreElemento}?`,
        text: 'Recuerda que esta acción es irreversible',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#50f8ac',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        focusCancel: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok, Bórralo',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log('Inside.. ');
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            this.submit();
        } else {
            console.log('No confirmed!! ');
        }
        });
});
</script>
```

And selecting both buttons, I get the same result.

[image]

I make a Video with this strange behaviour
[Video in drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hbAbWr9ps_gXYaUNSgah18vC3_EeskiT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/39tjwqrf/).

Comment: Yes, in jsfiddle.net works. In my Laravel 8 not.  is stranged.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the dialog it pops up... If you confirm the 'Are you sure?' then it will fire next dialog 'Deleted!'.

Comment: Not, in my space only works the cancel button.

Comment: Add console.log(result) before 'if (result.isConfirmed) {' inside the 'then' and watch what it tells you in console...

Comment: ```.then((result) => {
            console.log('Inside.. ');
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            this.submit();
        }```
print on console. What does not seem to work is the conditional, or in any case, the submit, not?

Comment: That's why I wrote to console.log(result) to look what it gives you. If you can see  logged out 'Inside.. ' than it works.... but the condition is wrong... And you can see what is wrong with it if you log it out.

Comment: Why the condition is wrong? is called if isconfirmed. I get the impression that something is wrong with result

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after many days I found the solution.

I changed the version in the Adminlte configuration of the installed sweetalert. I had version eight `sweetalert2@8`
which comes by default and I have passed it to ten. This has fixed the strange behavior.

```
 'Sweetalert2' => [
            'active' => true,
            'files' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'js',
                    'asset' => false,
                    'location' => '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score -1):

In simplest form variable `result` - is the result of button click... that is passed down from the `Swal()` to `.then()`

This is the simplest form of explanation I could give you, if you wish to understand this in detail you should learn more about the Promises and Asyncronise code in JS

The Code you have given in the question is working fine here is the jsfiddle link for the same [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nh4ck/fbsatn6q/1/)

if you add `!` before the  `result` then the 2nd pop-up will fire when you click the `cancel` button and nothing will happen if you click `yes` button

====Update====

1. Change the single quotes of .fas.fa-trash to double quotes

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>`

to
 `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>`

2. all Swal.fire() functions are missing `;`
3. also there is a lot of inconsistency while using a double quote, single quotes & Template literals

Please formate the script tag.. there could be one misplaced quote that might be causing this weird behaviour...

Also in the `.then()` block before you call the `if()` console log to see what you have inside of the result.

The rest of the code is looking good there should is no issue with the syntax/code while calling `Swal.fire()`

Comment: Yes, of course, that's why I don't understand why the confirmation button doesn't work. That is, if I press the confirmation button it does not enter the if.

Comment: I want it to work, without the negation '!'

Comment: i dont understand you want it to delete the file even if the user clicks cancel.. is that what you are trying to say

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the confirmation button doesn't work for me. And therefore, I use the cancel. I copy all the code for you to see what I want to do.

Comment: You will see that I am trying to confirm a deletion form. But for the swetalert to work for me I have to use the delete button. it's weird isn't it?

Comment: Can you check if there are errors in the browser's console?

Comment: 1. Change the single quotes of .fas.fa-trash to double quotes. - I change it ok.
2. all Swal.fire() functions are missing  - is missing? you can t see?
3. also there is a lot of inconsistency while using a double quote, single quotes & Template literals - I make the same double quote